# Render DropDown using Html.RenderAction without relaying on the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an 'ASP.NET MVC 4' project. I have a section with drop down and a button where you can select an action from the drop down and execute it clicking the button. This functionality is somehow separate from the certain view so I don't want to pass the values of the dropdown using the view model, instead I was wondering if it's possible (and good idea too) to somehow extract the whole logic and just invoke some method on the view to render the drop down and the button.
  Right now I'm thinking about`@{Html.RenderAction("Action")}}` in the view and in my controller something like:

```
    public async Task<Dictionary<int, string>> Actions(string batchId)
    {

        //try with hardcoded values first
        Dictionary<int, string> operations = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        operations.Add(1, "Retry");
        operations.Add(2, "Reject");

        return operations;
    }
```

Well, this is pretty basic because I really don't have idea how I can compose the drop down here. I have the values ready when I invoke `@{Html.RenderAction("Action")}}` I would like to have the drop down rendered as e result from calling the `RenderAction`

Comment: Include a ChildActionOnly method that returns a partial view that renders the dropdown and button and then call that method in the main view using `@{ Html.RenderAction("yourMethod") }`

Comment: You can also create a partial `_DropDownActions.cshtml` in `Views/Shared` folder, put your dropdown and button markup there, and call `@Html.Partial("_DropDownActions")` from any view.